# Convert column positive values to negative values VBA

Tags: vba, excel, loops

I know this has been asked several times but I'm quite confused on how to put the negative values for my column L:L in a loop. I can't get it to work. I've tried everything I researched. I'd appreciate any help.

```
 Option Explicit
Sub Importpaymentsales()
    Dim fpath As Variant
    Dim wb As Excel.Workbook
    Dim ws As Excel.Worksheet
    Dim Text As String
    On Error GoTo terminatemsg

    Set wb = Excel.ActiveWorkbook
    Set ws = Excel.ActiveSheet

    fpath = Application.GetOpenFilename(Filefilter:="text Files(*.txt; *.txt), *.txt; *.txt", Title:="Open Prepayment Sales Report")

    If fpath = False Then Exit Sub

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False

    Text = getTextfileData(fpath)
    If Len(Text) Then
        ProcessData Text
        AdjustDates
    Else
        MsgBox fpath & " is empty", vbInformation, "Import Cancelled"
        Exit Sub

    End If
    ws.Range("J:L").Value = ws.Range("J:L").Value
    ws.Range("J:L").numberformat = "#,##0.00"


    ws.Range("O:Q").Value = ws.Range("O:Q").Value
    ws.Range("O:Q").numberformat = "#,##0.00"

    Columns.EntireColumn.AutoFit
    Sheets(1).Move Before:=wb.Sheets(1)

terminatemsg:
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True
    If Err.Number <> 0 Then MsgBox Err.Number & " " & Err.Description

End Sub

Sub ProcessData(Text As String)
    Dim x As Long, y As Long, z As Long
    Dim data, vLine

    data = Split(Text, vbCrLf)
    x = 2
    Range("A1:R1").Value = Array("Supplier Name", "Supplier Number", "Inv Curr Code CurCode", "Payment CurCode", "Invoice Type", "Invoice Number", "Voucher Number", "Invoice Date", "GL Date", "Invoice Amount", "Withheld Amount", "Amount Remaining", "Description", "Account Number", "Invoice in USD", "Withheld in USD", "Amt in USD", "User Name")

    For y = 0 To UBound(data)
        If InStr(data(y), "|") Then
            vLine = Split(data(y), "|")
            If Not Trim(vLine(0)) = "Supplier" Then

                For z = 0 To UBound(vLine)
                    vLine(z) = Trim(vLine(z))

                    If vLine(z) Like "*.*.*.*.*.*.*.*.*.*.*.*.*.*.*" Then vLine(z) = Left(vLine(z), InStr(vLine(z), ".") + 2)

                Next
                Cells(x, 1).Resize(1, UBound(vLine) + 1).Value = vLine
                x = x + 1
                'Range("L2:L").Value = Range("L2:L").Value * (-1)
                Range("L2:L").Value = Abs(rng.Offset(teller - 1, -2).Value) * -1
            End If

        End If
    Next

End Sub
```

Comment: Where is your loop? What specific problem(s) are you having with this loop? (This is a very fundamental concept, see overview of [`For Each...Next`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/gg264596.aspx) and [`For...Next`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/gg251601.aspx) (the latter which requires indexing).

Comment: Hi david! under subProcessdata is where my loop is happening since the macro is importing data from a text file into an excel file. what I want is under the column L where it has positive and also some negative values I want to make it a all negative values.

Comment: Code doesn't compile, for starters, so is difficult to interpret... `rng` variable is undeclared and unassigned, you'll get an `Object Required` error on the line with `Range("L2:L").Value = Abs(rng...` statement. `teller` variable is also undeclared/unassigned. This statement also executes at *each* iteration of your `For y` loop, overwriting values from previous iteration.

Comment: Try changing `Range("L2:L").Value = Abs(rng.Offset(teller - 1, -2).Value) * -1` to `Cells(x - 1, "L").Value = Abs(vLine(11)) * -1`.  If that works and does what you want, it can be improved by moving the multiplication earlier (before placing `vLine` into the row) but it would be nice to know whether that is what you are after before refactoring the code for you.

Comment: got my code working ! thank you geniuses!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
  Dim r As Range
  For Each r In Range(Range("L2"), Range("L2").End(xlDown))
    If IsNumeric(r.Value) Then r.Value = -Abs(r.Value)
  Next
```

ps: I suppose you don't have blank cells in-between in column L, if you do then a slight modification is needed.

Here it is:

```
Dim r As Range
For Each r In Range(Range("L2"), Range("L" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp))
    If Not IsEmpty(r.Value) Then If IsNumeric(r.Value) Then r.Value = -Abs(r.Value)
  Next
```

Comment: ohh what if there'll be blank cells?

Comment: I added it to the answer ;)

Comment: you're amazing! Thank you so much :)