# Making all cell values in range negative

Tags: excel, vba

I am currently trying to do two things.

1) Swap values in two columns. The values are initially listed as Longitude then Latitude. I want Latitude to be listed first and I accomplish this in the first part of the code.

2) Problem Area. The longitudes are published as a positive value, but need to be negative, as a negative value will provide the correct location. I found an answer on

[Convert column positive values to negative values VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40732882/convert-column-positive-values-to-negative-values-vba)

to make negative all values in a range and include the blank cell values in the range. I tried altering the code to match my needs but am getting a Run Time Error '1004' - Method 'Range' of object '_Global' failed.

If anyone could help me out it would be greatly appreciated!

```
Public Sub CorrectLongitude()

    Dim tempRange As Variant
    Dim Longitude As Range
    Dim Latitude As Range

    '1) Swap Longitude and Latitude

    Worksheets("Raw_Data").Activate

    Set Longitude = Worksheets("Raw_Data").UsedRange.Columns("AR")
    Set Latitude = Worksheets("Raw_Data").UsedRange.Columns("AS")

    tempRange = Longitude.Cells
    Longitude.Cells.Value = Latitude.Cells.Value
    Latitude.Cells.Value = tempRange

    '2) Make Longitude values negative
    'Variable "Latitude is used as Latitude now contains the longitude values from above

    For Each Latitude In Range(Range("AS"), Range("AS" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp))

        If Not IsEmpty(Latitude.Value) Then If IsNumeric(Latitude.Value) Then Latitude.Value = -Abs(Latitude.Value)

        Next

End Sub
```

Comment: Should you add the Excel tag?

Comment: added. I saw the "Excel-VBA" tag was pending removal so I had only tagged vba.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're effectively calling the range `Range(Range("AS"),Range("AS1000"))`.  You're missing the first row reference.

```
For Each Latitude In Range(Range("AS1"), Range("AS" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp))
```

Edit: A personal suggestion, don't use `For each Latitude`, since you have `Latitude` as a defined range elsewhere and this might confuse VBA/yourself.  I typically do `Dim cel as Range // For each cel in ...`.  If you try and use `Latitude.Cells.Value` after the `For` loop, it'll be a much different result than when you called it before.

You might be able to do `For each cel in Latitude`, assuming that using the `UsedRange` in `Set Latitude = ...` includes all the used rows you need.